# Calling Functions from AngularJs Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, frontend, front-end-optimization

I need to insert a header in my AngularJS application.

I used to have a **header** and **header controller** containing `login/logout` functions since the header contains the *username* and `login/logout`.

Now I changed this to **header directive**, but in order to use the header in all the application pages I have to repeat writing the `login/logout` function and get the username in all the other pages controllers which is obviously repetitive and inefficient.

I'm new to AngularJS so I wonder if there is a good practice to solve this issue. May I write these functions in the directive itself instead and just pass the username from the controllers, is it a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to create a service with login/logout functions.

Then you just have to inject your service in your directive.

Take a look here : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services